# performing math on an array of strings(with numbers inside) with a loop of math operators

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings and the strings hold numbers inside of them. I also have a set of operations i need to perform on those numbers. They follow the order of +, -,*, /. if the amount of numbers is more than 4 then it goes back to the plus sign.

```js
  function calculate(n, operator, b) {
    switch (operator) {
      case 1:
        n += b;
        return n;
      case 2:
        n -= b;
        return n;
      case 3:
        n *= b;
        return n;
      case 4:
        n /= b;
        return n;
    }
}
numberArray = ["23", "44", "99", "324", "19"]
 let n=0;
let c = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {

    calculate(n, c, parseInt(numberArray[i]));
    if ( c < 4) {
      c++;
    } else {
      c=1;
    }
  }
console.log(n);
```

for some reason the switch statement doesn't run correctly. it doesn't perform the operations and return the `n` back so i can get the total from the calculations.

Comment: You never use or store the return value, how do you expect to get anything from the function? Functions are *pass by value*, and it does not calculate in place. Reassign as necessary.

Comment: Expanding on @AndrewL.'s point: The `switch` almost certainly works just fine. You just can't know, because you don't do anything with the result.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder i thought the `n += b;` in the function would update the value of n. ;X I guess I still lack some of the basic knowledge from javascript

Comment: @sourlemonaid As I mentioned, arguments are passed by value, not references. The `n` inside `calculate` has nothing to with the one outside. Same goes for any other variable in the function. The function has local variables which copy *value* of passed arguments.

Comment: @Andrew L. thanks Andrew, i understand now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i thought the `n += b`; in the function would update the value of `n`.

It does, but that `n` isn't the `n` in your code *calling* `calculate`. It's the `n` that's an argument to `calculate`. When you do:

```
calculate(n, c, parseInt(numbersArray[i]));
```

the **value** of `n` is passed into `calculate`, not something that refers to the variable itself. (This is called "passing by value." JavaScript always passes the *value* of a variable.) The argument is like a local variable; updating it has no effect outside the function.

Simply use the result:

```
n = calculate(n, c, parseInt(numbersArray[i]));
```

Updated snippet:

```js
function calculate(n, operator, b) {
    switch (operator) {
      case 1:
        n += b;
        return n;
      case 2:
        n -= b;
        return n;
      case 3:
        n *= b;
        return n;
      case 4:
        n /= b;
        return n;
    }
}
numberArray = ["23", "44", "99", "324", "19"]
 let n=0;
let c = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {

    n = calculate(n, c, parseInt(numberArray[i]));
    if ( c < 4) {
      c++;
    } else {
      c=1;
    }
  }
console.log(n);
```

Of course, this means your `switch` can be simpler:

```
switch (operator) {
  case 1:
    return n + b;
  case 2:
    return n - b;
  case 3:
    return n *= b;
  case 4:
    return n / b;
}
```

Just FWIW, there's a clever way to update `c` as well, to avoid the `if`:

```
c = (c % 4) + 1;
```

That'll wrap around for you.

Comment: ahhh! alright, it makes perfect sense now. Thank you! I was scratching my head for hours over what was going on.

Comment: @sourlemonaid: :-) FWIW, if you're starting with 0, it's `c = (c + 1) % 4` (that goes 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3...) Both forms (1-4 and 0-3) are really handy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a more compact version without the switch structure, but with an array for the functions.

It works with the index and is zero based, so no hassle with the first or last item, just take the modulo operator `%` with the length of the array and get the right index.

```js
let array = ["23", "44", "99", "324", "19"],
    fn = [(a, b) => a + b, (a, b) => a - b, (a, b) => a * b, (a, b) => a / b],
    n = array.reduce((n, a, i) => fn[i % fn.length](n, a), 0);

console.log(n);
```